# Turning Triangle Into Koch Snowflake Using WebGL

Tags: javascript, webgl

Trying to wrap my head around this. I have the following WebGL code which draws a triangle:

```
"use strict";

var canvas;
var gl;

var points = [];

window.onload = function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");

    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(canvas);
    if (!gl) { alert("WebGL isn't available"); }

    var vertices = [
        vec2(-1, -1),
        vec2(0, 1),
        vec2(1, -1)
    ];

    // draw a triangle; this is the current output of the program
    triangle(vertices[0], vertices[1], vertices[2]);

    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);


    var program = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader");
    gl.useProgram(program);

    var bufferId = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(points), gl.STATIC_DRAW);


    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);

    render();
};

function triangle(a, b, c) {
    points.push(a, b, c);  // (-1, -1), (0, 1), (1, -1) 
}

function render() {
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, points.length);
}
```

Starting with this [equilateral] triangle, I want to turn it into a Koch snowflake. I have the algorithm thanks to [Wikipedia's entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake#Construction), but my inexperience with JavaScript makes this a bit difficult. I understand that only minor changes to the above code are needed in order to turn the triangle into a Koch snowflake. How would I code the algorithm required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method to make a Koch snowflake is to recursively make a bunch of
triangles, written in pseudocode:

```
/* Return the vertices of a Koch triangle who's left and right sides have
   Koch triangles sticking out of them (recursive).

   pos: The position of the triangle
   dir: The direction triangle should point in
   side: The length of one side of the triangle
   iterations: The number of triangle babies to make
*/
function kochTriangle(pos, dir, side, iterations):
    tri = a big equilateral triangle

    if iterations == 1:
        return tri
    else:
        leftTri = recursively create a little kochTriangle on the left side
                  of tri with iterations - 1
        rightTri = recursively create a little kochTriangle on the right
                   side of tri with iterations - 1

        return concat(tri, leftTri, rightTri)
```

Note that this will only create the top half of a Koch snowflake, you'll have
to use this function to create one big Koch triangle pointing up and one
smaller one sitting on the bottom pointing down (hard to explain). You can use
either vector math or trigonometry to figure out where exactly to position
`leftTri` and `rightTri`.

I though this was a cool challenge, so I actually went ahead and had my own
crack at it. I've put mine in a runnable snippet below. You can look at the code below if you're stuck, but it's much more rewarding to figure it out yourself.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mcjohnalds45/3jghL52d/)

```js
var SNOWFLAKE_ITERATIONS = 5;
var SNOWFLAKE_SIZE = 1.5;

// How much smaller a triangle's child should be. A traditional Kotch
// snowflake should be 1/3. Change this value to get cool shapes.
var SNOWFLAKE_CHILD_SCALE = 1 / 3;

// Canvas element
var canvas;

// WebGL context
var gl;

// Vertices of the snowflake
var snowflakeVerticies;

// Buffer storing the snowflake's vertices
var snowflakeVertexBuffer;

// Vertex shader attribute
var aPositionAttrib;

function main() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("c");
    gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
    initSnowflakeVertices();
    initShaders();
    initBuffers();
    drawScene();
}

// Initialize the snowflake's vertices
function initSnowflakeVertices() {
    // We have two Koch triangles that make up the snowflake: t1 and t2. t1
    // is the top and sides of the snowflake, t2 gives the bottom.

    var t1Side = SNOWFLAKE_SIZE;
    var t2Side = t1Side * SNOWFLAKE_CHILD_SCALE;

    var t1Height = eqTriHeight(t1Side);
    var t2Height = eqTriHeight(t2Side);

    var snowFlakeHeight = t1Height + t2Height;
    var base = vec2(0.0, t2Height - snowFlakeHeight / 2);

    var t1Dir = vec2(0.0, 1.0);
    var t2Dir = vec2(0.0, -1.0);

    var t1 = kochTriangle(base, t1Dir, t1Side, SNOWFLAKE_ITERATIONS);
    var t2 = kochTriangle(base, t2Dir, t2Side, SNOWFLAKE_ITERATIONS - 1);

    // To clearly see the difference between t1 and t2, you can remove
    // the .concat(t2) to hide t2.
    snowflakeVerticies = t1.concat(t2);
}

// Initialize the shader program
function initShaders() {
    var program = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(program, compileShader("shader-fs"));
    gl.attachShader(program, compileShader("shader-vs"));
    gl.linkProgram(program);
    gl.useProgram(program);

    aPositionAttrib = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aPosition");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aPositionAttrib);
}

// Initialize a buffer and put the snowflake's vertices in it
function initBuffers() {
    snowflakeVertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, snowflakeVertexBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(snowflakeVerticies), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

function drawScene() {
    gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, snowflakeVertexBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(aPositionAttrib, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, snowflakeVerticies.length / 2);
}

// Create the vertices of a Koch triangle who's left and right sides have
// Koch triangles sticking out of them (recursive).
//
// base: The position vector of the base of the triangle
// dir: The unit vector direction triangle should point in
// side: The length of one side of the triangle
// iterations: The number of triangle babies to make
//
// Note that the bottom of the Koch triangle doesn't have another triangle
// sticking out, this is so we don't create unecessary triangles.
function kochTriangle(base, dir, side, iterations) {
    // tri is the big triangle that has two little triangles sticking out of
    // it's sides.
    var tri = eqTri(base, dir, side);
    var leftVert = vec2(tri[0], tri[1]);
    var rightVert = vec2(tri[2], tri[3]);
    var topVert = vec2(tri[4], tri[5]);

    if (iterations == 1) {
        return tri;
    } else {
        var leftBase = midpoint(leftVert, topVert);
        var leftDir = topVert.minus(leftVert).rotate90DegreesCCW().normalize();
        var leftTri = kochTriangle(leftBase, leftDir, side * SNOWFLAKE_CHILD_SCALE, iterations - 1);

        var rightBase = midpoint(rightVert, topVert);
        var rightDir = topVert.minus(rightVert).rotate90DegreesCW().normalize();
        var rightTri = kochTriangle(rightBase, rightDir, side * SNOWFLAKE_CHILD_SCALE, iterations - 1);

        return tri.concat(leftTri).concat(rightTri);
    }
}

// Create the vertices of an equilateral triangle.
//
// base: The position vector of the base of the triangle
// dir: The unit vector direction triangle should point in
// side: The length of one side of the triangle
function eqTri(base, dir, side) {
    var height = eqTriHeight(side);
    var leftVert = dir.rotate90DegreesCCW().scale(side / 2).plus(base);
    var rightVert = dir.rotate90DegreesCW().scale(side / 2).plus(base);
    var topVert = dir.scale(height).plus(base);
    return [
        leftVert.x, leftVert.y,
        rightVert.x, rightVert.y,
        topVert.x, topVert.y
    ];
}

// Get the height of an equilateral triangle with a given side length
function eqTriHeight(side) {
    return Math.sqrt(3) / 2 * side;
}

// A minimal 2D vector class. Example usage:
//
// x = vec2(1, 2);
// y = x.rotate90DegreesCW();
// z = x.plus(y);
function vec2(x, y) {
    var v = {x: x, y: y};

    v.plus = function(w) {
        return vec2(v.x + w.x, v.y + w.y);
    };

    v.minus = function(w) {
        return vec2(v.x - w.x, v.y - w.y);
    };

    v.scale = function(a) {
        return vec2(v.x * a, v.y * a);
    };

    v.rotate90DegreesCW = function() {
        return vec2(v.y, -v.x);
    };

    v.rotate90DegreesCCW = function() {
        return vec2(-v.y, v.x);
    };

    v.normalize = function() {
        return v.scale(1 / v.length());
    };

    v.length = function() {
        return Math.sqrt(v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y);
    };

    return v;
}

// Return the midpoint of two vectors
function midpoint(v, w) {
    return v.plus(w).scale(1 / 2);
}

// Compile and return the shader in the given element.
function compileShader(id) {
    var script = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!script) {
        return null;
    }

    var str = "";
    var k = script.firstChild;
    while (k) {
        if (k.nodeType == 3) {
            str += k.textContent;
        }
        k = k.nextSibling;
    }

    var shader;
    if (script.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
        shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    } else if (script.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
        shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    gl.shaderSource(shader, str);
    gl.compileShader(shader);

    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        console.error(id, gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
        return null;
    }

    return shader;
}

main();
```

```html
<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    attribute vec2 aPosition;

    void main(void) {
        gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
</script>

<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    void main(void) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    }
</script>

<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, John!